# Adding Multiple tabs in crystal reports

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

So i am really new to crystal reports. I have two queries that i want the results to be displayed in crystal reports.

[image: Crystal Report]

Now here is the first tab for the results of the first query. Now how do i add second tab for the results of the query.

I have been searching the web but haven't found something for it.

i am using crystal reports for visual studio 2012

Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "add" tabs. There is a "Main Report" tab and when you preview the report, a "Main Report Preview" tab will automatically be added. If you add a subreport, a subreport tab will get added, and so on.
If you want to see the result of two queries in one  report, you will have to add a subreport to your main report and display your data there.

Comment: Wow thanks it seems i was searching wrong words like multiple tabs etc. Anyways i have implemented subreports and if i have implemented them correct they must be clicked before a new tab is generated. I have done the project for now but i was looking more for basically a control similar to tabcontrol in winforms.

Answer (score -1):

The tabs you see are more like a path tree. When you open a subreport you can click on the main report tab and go back there. If you need to jump to a different set of data you can use grouping and jump to the right group using report group tree. Keep in mind that crystal reports supports just one datasource per report so whatever you are presenting should be in the same datasource.